# Работа с графикой

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день. Наткнулся на вот такой пример в учебнике:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame  = new Frame();
        frame.start();
    }
}
class Frame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Paint oval;
    private int x,y;
    Frame(){
        x = y = 120;
        frame =  new JFrame();
        oval = new Paint();
    }
    public void start() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(oval);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int count = 0;count <400;count++) {
            x++;
            y++;
            oval.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
    class Paint extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillOval(x,y, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Данный код рисует окружность в окне и используя цикл перерисовывает её, перемещая по диагонали. Так вот, изначально автор не добавлял эти две строки кода:

```
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

То есть не зарисовывал всё окно белым цветом перед рисованием фигуры на новой позиции. В результате фигура расплывалась. Как по мне это костыль. 
 Когда я писал этот пример, я в учебник не смотрел, и метод `repaint();` вызывал не у класса Paint, а у формы JFrame, у меня сразу всё нормально отображалось.  Так вот собственно вопрос, какой из методов вы считаете целесообразней использовать? 
Вот мой код:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame  = new Frame();
        frame.start();
    }
}
class Frame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Paint oval;
    private int x,y;
    Frame() {
        x = y = 120;
        frame =  new JFrame();
        oval = new Paint();
    }
    public void start() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(oval);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int count = 0;count <400;count++) {
            x++;
            y++;
                **frame.repaint();**

            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
    class Paint extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillOval(x,y, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пример так себе, учит плохому, я про создание анимации через Thread.sleep

Comment: @StrangerintheQ он не посвящен созданию анимации средствами java. Здесь акцентируется внимание на использование внутренних классов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще ошибка в том, что в переопределённом методе `paintComponent` необходимо вызвать родительский метод:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g); // <<<
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillOval(x,y, 100, 100);
}
```

Он в частности и очистит фон и тогда вызов `oval.repaint()` будет работать как положено. Про это хорошо написано в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) к родительскому методу:

> Further, if you do not invoke super's implementation you must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

Что примерно переводится как:

> Далее, если вы не вызовете родительскую реализацию, вы должны учесть непрозрачность компонента, а именно, если он непрозрачный, вам необходимо полностью залить фон непрозрачным цветом. Если вы этого не сделаете, вы увидите визуальные артефакты.

Что мы и наблюдаем. Так что либо вызвать `super.paintComponent(g)`, либо залить вручную (как у вас в коде). А как раз замена на `frame.repaint()` — это костыль, который скрывает истинную проблему и делает лишнюю работу (вам же не нужно перерисовывать всё окошко, нужно только содержимое перерисовать).